# Activiti Modeler Missing Feature

Tags: eclipse-plugin, bpmn, activiti

Using the activiti-modeler how can a user task be created with a defined human performer?

I realize that this is entirely possible within the eclipse GUI plugin or by coding the XML by hand, but the purpose would be to allow general users to utilize the activiti-modeler to create their own processes and to deploy them as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the task properties, and set the TaskType to "User".

Comment: but from there how do i actually set that user?

Comment: Have you tried the Eclipse modler? It is a bit flakey, but may be more intuitive.